# Error in XSL - "... does not identify an external Java class"

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

My xsl stylesheet begins with the following:

```
<xsl:transform
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:b64="net.sf.saxon.value.Base64BinaryValue"
xmlns:fos="java.io.FileOutputStream" exclude-result-prefixes="b64 fos">
...
```

When I run my webapp I get the following error message:

"The URI net.sf.saxon.value.Base64BinaryValue does not identify an external Java class"

From the error message I think this means that I don't have the required jar file.

1. Where can I locate/download this jar file?
2. In which folder(s) should I put this jar file? (tomcat/lib folder? My WEB-INF/lib folder?)
3. Is there anything else I should take note?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here is a list of jars](http://www.findjar.com/class/net/sf/saxon/value/Base64BinaryValue.html) that contain that class.  it should work fine in either of the locations you give (in the first case, for all applications; in th second for that specific application - i would normally use the latter).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this error message comes from Saxon 6.5.x, which is the old Saxon XSLT 1.0 processor. The stylesheet is apparently written to work with a more recent version of Saxon (the current release is 9.4).